# CLLocationManager giving wrong location updates

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, cllocationmanager

I am working on a tracking app, which needs to display the tracking path on map. When I start updating location and does not move the device after the installation, the locationManagar reports wrong location updates,

[image]

I am drawing a route based on location points reported,

Also when user is driving in a vehicle at high speed on straight road, it shows glitches like this as well,

**How can I ignore these erroneous location updates**.

You can download the app [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sabminder-best-real-time-gps/id640828731?mt=8) and test yourself

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, you can use lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy and you can calculate the distance covered as well from last known location and can set an offset, whether the new location is X meters away or Not? and also CoreMotion to actually check whether the device was moving or not based on your requirements.

Comment: @zaheer kindly provide more detail like a sample code for it

Comment: I'll update tomorrow

Comment: @zaheer can you please help me.. how can i ignore the the wrong location

Comment: You can validate the location updates to be Valid or Invalid, Please see this gist. https://gist.github.com/mrzaheerabbas/f4abe301f443411f51feb1decc6d2caf

Comment: You can modify different things according to your accuracy level, and requirement

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Horizontal Accuracy check this to make sure you have an accurate location. For example below 10meters or below zero:

```
    // test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement
    if (lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
```

And make sure you have a new location because it will return the last one default:

```
// test the age of the location measurement to determine if the measurement is cached
        // in most cases you will not want to rely on cached measurements
        NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[lastLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (locationAge > 5.0)
            return;
```

Also make sure you set the right desiredAccuracy on the CLLocationManager. For example:

```
_manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
```

Comment: I did all these tricks, but unfortunately none of these worked for me.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with the current code.